# weird bug with submit flask

Tags: python, flask

my html code:

```html
<body class="u-body">
    <section class="u-clearfix u-custom-color-3 u-section-1" id="sec-894d">
        <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
            <h1 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-1">תענה על השאלות הבאות</h1>
            <div class="u-form u-form-1">
                <form action="#" method="POST" class="u-clearfix u-form-spacing-15 u-form-vertical u-inner-form" style="padding: 0px;" source="custom" name="form" action="/backtohome">
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-name">
                        <label for="name-6797" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label"></label>
                        <input type="text" id="name-6797" name="name" class="u-border-6 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-26 u-input-1" required="" placeholder="my question">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-group-2">
                        <label for="text-8918" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label"></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="my question" id="text-8918" name="image" class="u-border-6 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-26 u-input-2" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-group-3">
                        <label for="text-da53" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label"></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="my question" id="text-da53" name="serverlink" class="u-border-6 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-26 u-input-3" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-message">
                        <label for="message-6797" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label">Address</label>
                        <textarea placeholder="my question" rows="4" cols="50" id="message-6797" name="botinfo" class="u-border-6 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-26 u-input-4" required=""></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-group-5">
                        <label for="text-d01b" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label"></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="my question" id="text-d01b" name="notes" class="u-border-6 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-26 u-input-5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-align-center u-form-group u-form-submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="u-btn u-btn-round u-btn-submit u-button-style u-radius-15">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

my python code

```py
@app.route("/disbuy", methods=["POST", "GET"])
async def disbuy():
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form_data = await request.form
            notes = form_data["notes"]
            if not notes:
                # my code
                return redirect(url_for("backtohome"))
            else:
                # my code
                return redirect(url_for("backtohome"))
        else:
            return await render_template("disbuy.html")
    except:
        return redirect(url_for("loginerror"))
```

my error:
it's not redirect to backtohome

Comment: Why don't you add some print statements inside your Python code to see which lines are executed?

Comment: I did it and the redirect doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You have your action to `action="/backtohome"`. Change that to `action="/disbuy"`:

```
<body class="u-body">
    <section class="u-clearfix u-custom-color-3 u-section-1" id="sec-894d">
        <div class="u-clearfix u-sheet u-sheet-1">
            <h1 class="u-text u-text-default u-text-1">תענה על השאלות הבאות</h1>
            <div class="u-form u-form-1">
                <form method="POST" class="u-clearfix u-form-spacing-15 u-form-vertical u-inner-form" style="padding: 0px;" source="custom" name="form" action="/disbuy">
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-name">
                        <label for="name-6797" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label"></label>
                        <input type="text" id="name-6797" name="name" class="u-border-6 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-26 u-input-1" required="" placeholder="my question">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-group-2">
                        <label for="text-8918" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label"></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="my question" id="text-8918" name="image" class="u-border-6 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-26 u-input-2" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-group-3">
                        <label for="text-da53" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label"></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="my question" id="text-da53" name="serverlink" class="u-border-6 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-26 u-input-3" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-message">
                        <label for="message-6797" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label">Address</label>
                        <textarea placeholder="my question" rows="4" cols="50" id="message-6797" name="botinfo" class="u-border-6 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-26 u-input-4" required=""></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-form-group u-form-group-5">
                        <label for="text-d01b" class="u-form-control-hidden u-label"></label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="my question" id="text-d01b" name="notes" class="u-border-6 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-26 u-input-5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="u-align-center u-form-group u-form-submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="u-btn u-btn-round u-btn-submit u-button-style u-radius-15">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Comment: <section class="u-clearfix u-custom-color-3 u-section-1" id="sec-894d" action="/backtohome">
this didnt work

Comment: Why would you expect this to solve the problem? Can you provide an explanation of what hypothesis you're working off of?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @devil I said to change it to /disbuy

Comment: You also define action twice